# Memory Leak при передаче объекта в качестве аргумента

Tags: c#, windows-8, утечка-памяти, xaml

При передаче объекта "MyClass" в качестве аргумента мы получаем, что каждый раз создается новый инстанс класса и никогда не уничтожается.

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), new MyClass());

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() 
    {
    }
}
```

[image]

Почему это может происходить?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: А как Вы определили, что он никогда не уничтожается?

Comment: > и никогда не уничтожается

с чего вы взяли?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, после 13 хождений по страницам и отработки GC.Collect не должно оставаться объектов которые уже ни кем не используются.
Смотрю в "Analyze —> Performance and Diagnostics -> Analyze memory usage" там-же есть возможность вызвать сборщик мусора.

Comment: Я думаю совершенно не обязательно, т.к. необходимость убивать объект рождается только тогда, когда выявляется нехватка памяти, ибо это сама по себе не быстрая операция и делать её лишний раз, только чтобы была, - убийство смысла самого понятия сборщика мусора. Хотите следить за памятью - пишите нативно на плюсах :-)

Comment: > ибо это сама по себе не быстрая операция

разумеется. Потому что помимо собственно удаления объектов должна произойти перемаркировка объектов по поколениям, должен произойти вызов финализаторов освобождаемых объектов (у кого они есть), а также дефрагментация памяти, что тоже не такой быстрый процесс

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работая с .NET, программист должен помнить, что сборка мусора там недетерминирована, и что сборщик имеет собственные (очень умные и надежные, кстати) алгоритмы, благодаря которым он решает, когда, как и в каких количествах очищать память. Предсказывать это пользователь не может и должен, это лежит в сфере ответственности сборщика. Объекты в памяти, как известно, делятся на поколения, и чем выше поколение, тем реже по нему проходит сборка мусора (и, соответственно, тем дольше живут относящиеся к нему объекты).  Запуск сборки осуществляется по мере заполнения памяти, отведенной под поколения, и если в нем нет необходимости, то он может не выполняться достаточно долгое время. То есть необходимо понимать, что объект не будет удален сразу же, как на него не останется ссылок. Он может быть удален и позже. Поэтому говорить об утечках памяти, основываясь на том, что сборка мусора  выполняется не тогда, когда этого ожидает пользователь, как минимум неверно.

Сложно судить конкретно о вашем случае, не имея необходимых данных, но, вероятно, ваши объекты пережили несколько итераций сборки мусора и находятся в одном из старших поколений. Также более долгая и счастливая жизнь объекта возможна в случае наличия у него финализатора. В этом случае он даже пройдет процедуру "воскрешения" (об этом можно прочесть у старика Рихтера), что существенно оттянет срок его кончины.

В любом случае, вы всегда можете убедиться, что все ваши объекты успешно удаляются. Добавьте в класс финализатор, в котором опишите какое-нибудь логирование (вывод на консоль, в лог или что-то в этом роде), и вы сможете убедиться, что все ваши объекты успешно удаляются. Я сильно удивлюсь, если это окажется не так

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как мне убедиться, что данное подведение, как Вы утверждаете, это нормальное поведение?

Comment: >Не совсем понятно как мне убедиться что данное подведение, как Вы утверждаете, это нормальное поведение?

ну например почитать Рихтера. У него довольно подробно написано о принципах работы сборки мусора в CLR

Comment: Ржака, дядя. Забавные у Вас притензии.

Comment: >Я ждал более конструктивного предложения. Понятно что практиков тут нет, жаль. Спасибо.

давайте постараемся обойтись без детских обид. Каких именно предложений вы ждали? Боюсь, я не смогу предоставить вам исходники дотнетовского сборщика мусора для того, чтобы вы смогли их проанализировать. Если вы не желаете верить словам одного из наиболее авторитетных специалистов в этой области (это я не про себя, а про Рихтера, разумеется), то мне очень жаль, но в таком случае вам сложно помочь. Поэтому еще раз говорю - ознакомьтесь с принципами сборки мусора в .NET, тогда все встанет на свои места